# self complemetary graph

Tags: graph-theory

How to prove that there exists exactly two self- complementary graph with five vertices.
I am having difficutly to prove this.
I only know the definition of self- complementary graph.But I am unable to use it.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.